# Simulating a population to sample from

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to obtain similar results as the simulation study in chapter 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02926). In the following, I'll briefly explain how the population and the sample were generated.

The population consists of $N=10^7$ observations divided over $C=100$ clusters. Each cluster contains exactly $10^5$ observations. Observations are assigned a treatment dummy $W_i \in \left\{0,1\right\}$ where $\text{Pr}(W_i =0)=\text{Pr}(W_i =1)=1/2$. The outcome was generated as:

$Y_i = \tau_{C_i}\cdot W_i+\nu_i$,$\quad \nu_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

$\tau_{c}=1$ and $\tau_{c}=-1$ for exactly (!) half of the clusters, respectively.

The sample is obtained from this population by sampling $10^5$ observations completely randomly. For each observation we observe $Y_i, W_i, C_i\in\left\{1,\ldots,C\right\}$ and estimate the linear regression:

$Y_i = \alpha + \tau\cdot W_i+\varepsilon_i$

I have not been able to obtain the same results for $\hat{\rho}_{\hat{\varepsilon}}$ and $\hat{\rho}_{\hat{\varepsilon}W}$ which correspond to the within-cluster correlation of the residuals and the product of residuals and regressors, respectively.
Unfortunately, the authors only verbally explain how the estimates for the within-cluster correlations are calculated:

"We estimate these by first calculating the sample
variance of the residuals (regressors) with and without demeaning by cluster, and then taking the ratio of the difference of these two to the overall variance of the residuals (regressors)"

This is what I have done so far:

```
require(dplyr); require(tibble)
set.seed(1234)
popsize <- 10e6
eps <- rnorm(popsize)
tr <- rbinom(popsize,1,0.5)
C <- 100
wste <- rep(sample(rep(c(1,-1),times=50),100,rep=FALSE),each=popsize/C)
cl <- rep(c(1:100),each=popsize/C)
y <- wste*tr+eps
#create dataframe
dat <- as_tibble(list(y=y,cluster=cl,treat=tr,te=wste,eps=eps))
rm(tr,eps,te,wste,y)
#create sample#
sampsize <- 100000
df <- dat[sample(nrow(dat),sampsize,rep=FALSE),]
df <- arrange(df,cluster)
#number of observations per cluster#
nobscl <- unlist(count(df,cluster)[,2])
#run the regression and compute the correlations#
res <- lm(df$y~df$treat)
df <- add_column(df,residuals=res$residuals)
df <- add_column(df,prod=df$residuals*df$treat)

#de-mean the objects#
meanres <- rep(0,C)
for(i in 1:C){
  meanres[i] <- mean(df$residuals[df$cluster==i])
}

meanreg <- rep(0,C)
for(i in 1:C){
  meanreg[i] <- mean(df$treat[df$cluster==i])
}

meanprod <- rep(0,C)
for(i in 1:C){
  meanprod[i] <- mean(df$prod[df$cluster==i])
}
df <- add_column(df,demres=df$residuals-rep(meanres,times=nobscl))
df <- add_column(df,demreg=df$treat-rep(meanreg,times=nobscl))
df <- add_column(df,proddem=df$prod-rep(meanprod,times=nobscl))

#finally, compute the within-cluster variance according to the paper
rhoepshat <- (var(df$residuals)-var(df$demres))/var(df$residuals)
rhoreghat <- (var(df$treat)-var(df$demreg))/var(df$treat)
rhoepsregha <- (var(df$prod)-var(df$proddem))/var(df$prod)

round(c(rhoepshat,rhoreghat,rhoepsregha),5)
[1] 0.16686 0.00076 0.24875
```

Apart from $\hat{\rho}_W$ which is close to zero I fail to replicate the results for the other two correlations mentioned above.

**Questions**:

1.) Is there a universal definition of the within-cluster correlation?

2.) Is there an intuition why the within-cluster correlation of the residuals $\hat{\varepsilon}$ has to be zero?

3.) Did I fail to implement one or more of the sample chracteristics in the code snippet provided?

P.S. Please let me know if the problem has not been explained sufficiently clearly. I am happy to add further information if needed.

Comment: Please give us more details, rather then the reference alone. What exactly is your question? Also notice that if you are asking about code review alone, then this would be off-topic in here.